# Run a docker container using network host mode

Tags: node.js, docker, raspberry-pi, hypriot

I have a docker image, which i made starting from a `node` one for *RaspberryPi 1* ([hypriot/rpi-node](https://hub.docker.com/r/hypriot/rpi-node/)).
Inside it i have a `node.js` project using [noble](https://github.com/noble/noble), which is giving me `segmentation fault` error whenever i launch it.

I've already had this problem weeks ago, founding out that the solution was to run the docker container using `network host` mode.
The problem is that i don't remember how i did it...

Here's the docker's images list on my raspberry

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
62673100d037        rpi-noble           "/usr/bin/entry.sh /…"   4 weeks ago         Exited (139) 3 days ago                        nifty_hawking
```

Comment: Do you mean this? https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

Comment: Did you try the `history` command, to find out how you did it last time? You can do something like `history | grep host`.

Comment: @TomM If i'm not wrong, that's the command for creating a container in network host mode. I would like to run an existing one using that mode.

Comment: @Mark Nope, but i will! Thanks, i'll let you know.